# Find longest palindrome, code passes half test cases

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm trying to find the longest palindrome possible, given a String s.  Problem specifies that it's case-sensitive so 'A' != 'a'.  My attempt below passes 49 / 95 of Leetcode's test cases but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...

```
public class Solution {
    public int longestPalindrome(String s) {
        if (s.equals("")) {
            return 0;
        }
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (map.containsKey(c)) {
                map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        int total = 0;
        int greatestOdd = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            int value = entry.getValue();
            if (value % 2 == 0) {
                total += value;
            } else {
                if (value > greatestOdd) {
                    greatestOdd = value;
                }
            }
        }
        total += greatestOdd;
        return total;

    }
}
```

The idea is that a palindrome consists of characters whose counts are even and one character that has an odd count (or possibly 0 characters with an odd count).  So I keep track of all the character counts in a HashMap.

Then I loop through all the values in the HashMap and if they're even, add to total.  I also keep track of greatest odd (initialized to 0 in case there's no letter with an odd count).

I think it's the right idea but something is off...

Link to exercise: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindrome/?tab=Description

Comment: This isnt codereview. Can you atleast give us some comments? what does it do?

Comment: With that logic, a string like bbadd would be considered a palindrome?

Comment: Can you link to the excercise? I´d like to test it myself.

Comment: @samson yes, it's just whether you can rearrange the letters to form a palindrome (not whether it already is one)

Comment: Then you should make that a bit more clear in the question imo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is correct, but once you calculate the greatest odd value, you should remove it from the map and consider all the other characters occurring odd number of times.

You should make them even by subtracting 1, and adding it to your palindrome length:

My Code:

```
public int longestPalindrome(String s) {
    HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(map.containsKey(c)) {
            map.put(c,map.get(c)+1);
        } else {
            map.put(c,1);
        }
    }
    int maxOdd = 0;
    char maxOddChar = Character.MIN_VALUE;
    int palindromeLength = 0;
    for (Character c : map.keySet()) {
        if(map.get(c)%2==0) {
            palindromeLength += map.get(c);
        } else {
            if(maxOdd<map.get(c)) {
                maxOdd = map.get(c);
                maxOddChar = c;
            }
        }
    }
    palindromeLength += maxOdd;
    map.remove(maxOddChar);
    //Considering other odd characters as well  
    for (Character c : map.keySet()) {
        if(map.get(c)%2!=0) {
            palindromeLength += map.get(c)-1;
        }
    }
    return palindromeLength;
}
```

> Example: aabbbcccccdd
>
> ```
> Hashmap ->  a->2,b->3,c->5,d->2
> Greatest odd value = c->5
> Total palindrome length : a+d+c = 2+2+5 = 9
>
> // But you are missing b->3 can also be added 
> // in the palindrome, but using only 2 b's and neglecting 1
>
> Total palindrome length : 9+2 = 11
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Often, simplifying the code makes everything so clear you almost can't have bugs. For example:

```
List<Long> freqs = Arrays.stream(s.split("(<=.)")).stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o, Collectors.counting()))
  .values();
long length = freq.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue)
    .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).sum() -
  freqs.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue)
    .filter(n -> n % 2 == 1).max().orElse(0);
```

A mere 2 (albeit long) lines.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>